# Amazon Redshift - Intermittent session timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, npgsql

I am currently investigating an issue regarding an intermittent session timeout error when querying Amazon Redshift. 
This error tends to happen on the first connection of the "day", I am not sure the exact window. However, afterwards this error doesn't appear again for the rest of the "day". 
Audit logs from Amazon Redshift do not seem to contain in reference to the error, we can see the connection been initialized and then nothing.

We suspect it might have something to do with pooling, however, we have been unable to reliably replicate this error in our other environments, so it has been hard to investigate.

Exception as follows:

```cs
Npgsql.PostgresException: 57P01: terminating connection due to session timeout
  ?, in async IBackendMessage NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode)+ReadMessageLong(?)
  ?, in async Task<bool> NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(bool async, bool isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  ?, in bool NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
  ?, in async ValueTask<NpgsqlDataReader> NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) x 2
  ?, in NpgsqlDataReader NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
....
```

I was wandering if anybody has encountered similar scenarios, or may have an idea of where to investigate.

Comment: How are you 'connecting' to Redshift? Do you have some sort of connection from the previous day that it is trying to re-use?

Comment: You may want to turn on [keepalive](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/keepalive.html) to make sure your connection is closed because of inactivity during the night. Or you can clear the pool (`NpgsqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`) before attempting the first connection in the morning.